# Adding a Second Switch to the First Switch to connect more Computers

Tags: networking, router, switch, mac-address

[image]

I intend to have 3 PCs connected to Netgear GS108 `Switch 2`, which is connected to `Switch 1` which is connected to the Internet.

In the current setup that we have, access to the internet must be done through `Switch 1` which requires the MAC addresses of all clients connected to it to be registered, so I am finding a way to connect more clients to the internet without the hassle of registering their MAC addresses with `Switch 1` by using the second switch `Switch 2` whose MAC address is registered.

Can the 3 PCs are connected to `Switch 2` appear to `Switch 1` as just a single client `Switch 2`? Or will the MAC addresses of the 3 PCs be exposed to `Switch 1`?

Comment: The GS108 is just a simple switch. All it does is forward ethernet packets. It can not make 3 clients appear as one. For that you would need a router. Also I'm guessing that switch 1 is not just a switch but a router since it wouldn't be directly connected to the internet otherwise. Anyway are you sure you can't just register all MAC addresses with switch 1?

Comment: The MAC addresses will all be exposed.

Comment: @SpiderPig There's some bug in the MAC registration that makes it really difficult to access the internet. Does this mean I need a 8-port router instead of a switch?

Comment: Yes, you could replace switch 2 with a router. But you could then connect one or several switches to that router which means you can connect an arbitrary number of PCs through that one router and switch 1 will only see one MAC address.